# Talkback marker navigation in a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, accessibility, talkback

While Talkback mode is enabled, in a map fragment when i swipe left to right to get the talk back to fetch the next marker on the map, it repeats every marker twice. Any ideas how to fix this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found the solution? Same problem here

Comment: No, we marked it as undoable